# Is it possible to get all functions involved in function2 call on Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to know the functions involved in a demo on Matlab ? I mean starting from a function/Script `demo` can I have a tree of all involved files/functions on the current demo that has been called by the `demo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [`depfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/depfun.html).

Quote from the documentation -

```
depfun  Locate dependent functions of program file.
     TRACE_LIST = depfun(FUN) returns a cell array of files of the dependent
     functions of FUN.
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but is it possible to mention how deep it can go ?

Comment: I found it : `list = depfun(fun,'-toponly')`

Comment: @ALJIMohamed Yes, that's for listing out the functions that are input arguments to this main function, without going into the files/functions on which these called function depend upon.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, possibly more interactive, way to have a look at what **has been** used is to use the profiler:

```
profile on -history

 % now run some code or function

profile off
profile viewer
```

not really what it was designed for but could be used in this way